# Guardar string en un archivo txt

Tags: string, archivo, kotlin

Este es el código que estoy implementando, también lo he intentado de otras maneras, sin embargo en todas las ocasiones que lo ejecuto la aplicación se cierra inmediatamente

```
fun writeToFile() {
            val text = "Prueba texto"
            File("output.txt").writeText(text)
    }
```

**Acá lo invoco**

```
if (isUpdate){Toast.makeText(contx,"Editado :)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); writeToFile() }
                        else{Toast.makeText(contx,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
```

error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: output.txt (Read-only file system)

Comment: Si no pones más información no podemos ayudarte:¿No se muestra ningún error? ¿Quién llama a esta función?

Comment: Ya, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: La función se llama al realizar el Toast pero el problema es que tal vez el archivo no existe y no estas intentando crearlo, además recuerda que necesitas permisos @saheco

Answer (score -1):

Si deseas crearlo en esta ubicación no podrás realizarlo únicamente si tu dispositivo tiene permisos Root:

```
File("output.txt").writeText(text)
```

Te sugiero definir un path en el almacenamiento externo, pero antes de realizar esto es importante definas el permiso en tu archivo `androidmanifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

y además definas la petición manual de permisos para `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, agrego este ejemplo, agrega este método para obtener la respuesta al requerir el permiso:

```
  val REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_PERMISSION -> if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Jorgesys", "Se aceptaron permisos!")
            }
        }
    }
```

En el método `onCreate()` defines la petición:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_PERMISSION)
        } else {
            Log.d("Jorgesys", "Se tienen permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE!")
        }
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Es importante la definición del permiso ya que de otra forma no podrás crear un directorio o archivo y mucho menos escribir dentro del mismo.

---

**Crear archivo y escribir dentro de el en Kotlin**

Ahora lo que deseas es crear un archivo, y escribir dentro de el, lo cual se puede realizar de esta forma:

```
fun writeToFile() {
    //Define ruta en almacenamiento externo y si deseas un directorio.
    val path = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/misarchivos/")
    var success = true
    //Si el path no existe, trata de crear el directorio.
    if (!path.exists()) {
        success = path.mkdir()
    }

    //Si el path existe o creo directorio sin problemas ahora crea archivo.
    if (success) {
        val text = "Prueba texto"
        //Escribe texto en archivo.
        File(path,"output.txt").writeText(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.