# Registros en archivo .txt

Tags: android, kotlin, almacenamiento

estoy probando guardar en un archivo **.txt** algunas palabras contenidas en una **variable texto** al dar clic en un **botón**.
El inconveniente es que, debería estar guardando una secuencia de lo que ponga en la **variable texto**, sin embargo sólo guarda lo que le ponga a esta en la última ejecución.

```
var texto ="Registro 1"
        btnInt.setOnClickListener(){
            try {
                val archivo = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("notas.txt", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE))

                archivo.write(texto)

                archivo.flush()
                archivo.close()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Si en una próxima ejecución cambio el valor de texto (var texto = "Registro 2"), el resultado esperado es que en el archivo "notas.txt" aparezca

Registro 1

Registro 2

Pero, reitero, en este momento el valor que está plasmando es el de la última ejecución

Registro 2

Comment: hola @saheco veo que no revisaste https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144455/guardar-string-en-un-archivo-txt para saber como crear un archivo

Answer (score 1):

Debes revisar como crear un archivo y guardar texto dentro del archivo en Kotlin :

[Guardar string en un archivo txt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144455/guardar-string-en-un-archivo-txt)

En este caso si deseas crear un archivo y agregar información puedes usar el método [**appendText()**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/append-text.html)

```
var counter = 1;

fun writeToFile() {
    //Define ruta en almacenamiento externo y si deseas un directorio.
    val path = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/misarchivos/")
    var success = true
    //Si el path no existe, trata de crear el directorio.
    if (!path.exists()) {
        success = path.mkdir()
    }

    //Si el path existe o creo directorio sin problemas ahora crea archivo.
    if (success) {
         val text = "Prueba texto "  + counter++ + "\n"
        //Escribe texto en archivo.
        File(path,"output.txt").appendText(text)
    }
}
```

De esta forma al llamar el método puedes agregar texto al mismo, ejemplo:

```
Prueba texto 1
Prueba texto 2
Prueba texto 3
Prueba texto 4
Prueba texto 5
Prueba texto 6
Prueba texto 7
Prueba texto 8
Prueba texto 9
Prueba texto 10
Prueba texto 11
```